# rails 3 - how to assign the value to nested attribute using callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I have three models, Document, Section and Paragraph.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status

  has_many :sections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sections, :allow_destroy => :true

  private

  def assign_order_status
    section_statuses = sections.map(&:status)
    self.status = 
    if section_statuses.all? {|value| value == "completed" }
      "completed"
    elsif section_statuses.all? {|value| value == "new" }
      "new"
    else
      "inprocess"
    end
  end
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :document_id, :status

  belongs_to :document
  has_many :paragraphs, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs, :allow_destroy => :true

  private
  def assign_order_status
    paragraph_values = paragraphs.map(&:text)
    self.status = 
    if paragraph_values.all? {|value| !value.nil? }
      "completed"
    elsif paragraph_values.any? {|value| !value.nil? }
      "inprocess"
    else
      "new"
    end
  end
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :section_id, :text
  belongs_to :section 
end
```

I want to update status of Document and Section models.

For example, 'status' column in sections table is depending on 'text' column in paragraphs table.
simillarly, 'status' column in documents table is depending on 'status' column in sections table.

Briefly, for sections,

1. If all the *'text'* in paragraphs table is nil then the *'status'* of corresponding section have to change as "new".
2. If any one *'text'* column in paragraphs table is having value then the *'status'* of section have to change as "inprocess".
3. Otherwise status is "completed".

for document,

1. If all the *'status'* in section table is "new" then the *'status'* of corressponding document have to change as "new".
2. If any one *'status'* is "inprocess" then *'status'* of document have to change as "inprocess".
3. Otherwise is "completed".

**Problem:**

I am confusing which callbacks is suitable for assign_order_status method.

Because 'status' of Document is depending on Section's status and Section's status is depending on value of Paragraph.
But Rails validation and callbacks are running from parent to child. In my case, calculation of 'status' value is based from child to parent.

How to update status value for both document and section before starting validation ?

Please anyone help me to solve this.